# I don't know why my vba code is throwing a compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I get a dub or funtion not defined error. I created a command button on the sheet and wrote the code in the button sub i did not rename the button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 'fln = family last name
 'fn = first name
 'cn2 = child's name
 Dim fln As String, fn As String, i As Long
 Dim fln2 As String, fn2 As String, cn2 As String, j As Integer

 i = 2 'i is set to 2 to take into account column headers
 j = 1
 fln = Cell(i, 1).Value2
 fn = Cell(i, 2).Value2
 fln2 = Cell(i + 1, 1).Value2
 fn2 = Cell(i + 1, 2).Value2
 cn2 = Cell(i + 1, 7).Value2

 Do While i < Rows.Count
  'if the famlies last name and first name are the same as the ones in the 
   row below and the row below is not blank
   If fln = fln2 And fn = fn2 And fln2 <> "" Then
   ' move the childs name to the next free column on the original row
      Cell(i, 7 + j).Value2 = cn2
      'increment the column
      j = j + 1
      'delete the row with the duplicate
      Rows(i + 1).Delete
    'else move the dup checker down a row as the current row now has a 
     complete family listing
    Else
     i = i + 1
     'reset j
     j = 1
     Loop
```

'start checking for dup family rows again

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. It would also help if you gave us a snippet of the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: Well, by pasting the code into the VBE and trying to run it, the first thing it complains about is `Cell`.  You have never defined a `Sub` or `Function` called `Cell`, so it doesn't like it.  You probably meant `Cells` but, given that the VBE highlights the exact place you have the error, I'm surprised you haven't fixed it.   You are also missing an `End If` toward the bottom of the posted code.  I'm not sure what else will be wrong.

Comment: use CELLS(), not CELL().

Answer (score 0):

You didnt close your `IF` statement.

put `END IF` on the line right before `LOOP`

Comment: also, you have comments that you didnt put an apostrophe in front of...

Comment: Thanks for the advise.